# Bind action in uibutton -Reactive Cocoa

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I have declared a action as

```
var postAction: Action<String, Data, NSError>!
```

now what i want is to trigger this action when the button triggers.

```
 triggerBtn.reactive.pressed = CocoaAction(postAction)
```

But can't.How can i trigger some action when a button is pressed using reactive cocoa?

*I have figured out a way to observe the actions.*

```
self.testBtn.reactive.trigger(for: .touchUpInside).observe{ event in
        //do something
        print(event)

    }
```

**But cant figure out how to get the sender and bind Custom Action?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Action has an input of type `String`, but the default CocoaAction is no input (type `()`).

Depending on where your input should come from when the button is pressed, you can use either a fixed value (if its known at this point):

```
button.reactive.pressed = CocoaAction(postAction, input: "Some Input")
```

or an inputTransformer

```
button.reactive.pressed = CocoaAction(postAction) { sender in
    // Calculate input for the action when the button is pressed
    return "Some Value"
}
```

Comment: Can you say me how do i get the sender in this code please `self.pressBtn.reactive.trigger(for: .touchDown)...get sender`

Comment: Well, the sender is just the button thats being pressed. Only thing to keep in mind is to capture the button weakly as to not create a strong reference cycle: `button.reactive.trigger(for: .touchDown).observeValues { [weak button = button] in
    print("Sender: \(button)")
}`